# Linux Grub lan boot onion service

Tags: linux, сеть, grub, tor

В качестве эксперимента хочу настроить тонкого клиента с загрузку ОС по сети, но протокол передачи должен быть tor (с hidden service по адресу ergoiughdeioujgj.onion) Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли уже такая реализация и если нет то насколько сложно это сделать и в какую сторону двигаться?

Comment: А каким образом будет нода получать адреса? Начните хотя бы с простого,  с понимания, что onion — это довольно выскоуровневый протокол, чтобы возиться с загрузкой машины, ему для работы нужны и другие уровни модели OSI. (И да, сделать можно, но зачем, не очень понятно)

Comment: Ну а просто тонкий клиент ты делал? Прям по классике и чтобы работал? Или ты решил проглотить всё одним куском?

Comment: Тонкий клиент сделать не сложно, для этого даже grub не нужен будет, но там нет поддержки протокола тор. Я же хочу сделать чтобы мой ноутбук загружал ОС в любом месте при наличии интернета и это все было зашифровано. Может есть другие пути? Подскажите изучу их.

Comment: Можно ли загрузить легковесную ОСь с помощью которой загрузить образ и передать ему управление?

Comment: Насколько мне известно ноутбуки не умеют без какого-то софта TOR. Для tor Вам всё равно понадобится какой-то мало-мальский собранный tcp/ip стек чтоб загрузить образ, то есть вам придётся этот, назовём его абстрактно "инструмент" иметь с собой. Собсно вопрос: не проще ли собрать какую-то любую ОС будь то gentoo или arch и таскать её с собой (aka livecd) коль скоро факт наличия чего-то, что умеет ТОР в принципе неизбежно? К вопросу "загрузки и передачи управления" - можно использовать банальный `chroot` или любой образ ОС/контейнер.